# Writing decision statements on control layer

Tags: java, model-view-controller, java-8, option-type, api-design

In MVC pattern we are developing a `REST` application.

Service layer is returning `Optional<T>` where T could be any class.

So on `REST` `Controller` layer there is a conditional statement which tests if result is `Optional.empty` then return `[]` else return actual data.

```
return ABCService.getById("").map(send actual data).orElse(Collections.empty());
```

It's a bad practice to write this code on control layer??

We are returning `Optional<T>` because we don't want to return `null`. If we don't use that condition on Control layer we have to remove `Optional` returning from service layer too, which I don't think is a good practise.

Can someone please explain why adding above code is not a good practice, what could be consequences??

Comment: It’s irritating that `"DO SOMETHING"` and `"DO SOMETHING ELSE"` are *values*, which matches the intention of `map` and `orElse` while their contents suggests that you actually describe an action.

Comment: It's bad practice if the code is not presentation logic, and should thus not be in the controller. It's good practice if the code is presentation logic, and should thus be in the controller. So it all depends on what DO SOMETHING and DO SOMETHING ELSE actually are.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: If by "send actual data" (don't know why you don't post real code, instead of forcing us to guess), you mean "write data to the HTTP response", then it's definitely code that should be in the controller. What you should most probably do, however, is send back a 404 Not Found response if the resource can't be found, instead of sending back an empty collection. But again, posting a real example would help.

Comment: REST is a set of rules, or patterns (in light diferent sense than GoF). Correct REST design is build on HTTP comamnds. To tell the true, rules are broken many times, like implementing verbs other than PUT/POST/DELETE etc. This is not REST

Comment: @JacekCz REST is an architecture style, it is not built on HTTP

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thanks for correct word. But this not change main idea: S mean State, only direct stare interaction are allowed - 'verbs' or 'busines methods' (like in SOAP) are not orthodox REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are responsible for representing data in the format they are supposed to provide. They don't process raw data (operations like fetching/updating normally processed by services), they just tell how this data should look like.

Therefore, believing that the `.map(send actual data)` doesn't do anything related to the business logic layer, your code snippet is acceptable.

Another question remaining is how to properly write a method to process that case. According to "Clean Code", I would recommend writing two methods (for empty and non-empty data respectively).

Comment: was that helpful? if there are questions remaining, you are free to ask :)

Comment: Yes, there are many question.. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357565/writing-decision-statement-on-control-layer I asked this question here..N people are talking that I am making it hard returning **Optional<T>**.. Is it really so??
Is there anything I can do to make my APIs according to standard??